# SQLite ICU support on iOS project

Tags: ios, sqlite, icu

I need to support greeks characters (non-ascii) so I understand that I have to enable ICU on my sqlite version. Believe me that I tried every way that I found on the internet, but each time there is some kind of problem.

Actually I'm using [this library](https://github.com/swiftlyfalling/SQLiteLib) for compiling the custom version of SQLite and [this one](https://github.com/dbquarrel/icu4c-xcframework) to get the ICU framework.

In a completely blank project, these are the list of errors that I get:

```
Undefined symbol: std::__1::__call_once(unsigned long volatile&, void*, void (*)(void*))

Undefined symbol: std::__1::condition_variable::notify_all()

Undefined symbol: std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&)

Undefined symbol: std::__1::condition_variable::~condition_variable()

Undefined symbol: std::__1::mutex::lock()

Undefined symbol: std::__1::mutex::unlock()

Undefined symbol: std::__1::mutex::~mutex()

Undefined symbol: std::terminate()

Undefined symbol: vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info

Undefined symbol: vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info

Undefined symbol: vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info

Undefined symbol: operator delete(void*)

Undefined symbol: ___cxa_bad_typeid

Undefined symbol: ___cxa_begin_catch

Undefined symbol: ___cxa_pure_virtual

Undefined symbol: ___dynamic_cast

Undefined symbol: ___gxx_personality_v0

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there any simpler way to support non-ascii characters?

I tried to support ICU in my sqlite versione. I got a lot of compiling errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was missing the -lc++ flag in the Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags  [Flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYos0.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).